# Unable to setup fallback repositories in settings.xml for my Maven project using mirrors

Tags: maven, repository

I have a long setup of repository lookups in my project.

Some are defined in project poms, which look like incorrect to me -

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository>/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository</localRepository>
<servers>

    <server>
        <id>helloworld</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>somthing@123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>helloworld-snapshots</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>helloworld-releases</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
<server>
        <id>helloworld-snapshots-prepaid</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>helloworld-releases</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
</servers>


<mirrors>
       <mirror>
      <id>helloworld-releases</id>
 <mirrorOf>helloworld-releases</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>helloworld-snapshots</id>
  <mirrorOf>helloworld-snapshots</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-public/</url>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
  <profiles>
<profile>
  <id>helloworld</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
     <repository>
      <id>helloworld-releases</id>
      <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-releases</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>helloworld-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
      <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>

 </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>helloworld</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I modified this to add mirror id project-1, which is a mirrorOf * (based on my readings about mirrors) and also added the same repository inside  (I am not quite sure about this).

Following is the modified settings.xml -

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository>/Users/sandeepan.nath/.m2/repository</localRepository>
<servers>

    <server>
        <id>helloworld</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>somthing@123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>helloworld-snapshots</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>helloworld-releases</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
<server>
        <id>helloworld-snapshots-prepaid</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>helloworld-releases</id>
        <username>something</username>
        <password>something@123</password>
    </server>
</servers>


<mirrors>
       <mirror>
      <id>helloworld-releases</id>
 <mirrorOf>helloworld-releases</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>helloworld-snapshots</id>
  <mirrorOf>helloworld-snapshots</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-public/</url>
</mirror>


    <mirror>
            <id>project-1</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>

</mirrors>
  <profiles>
<profile>
  <id>helloworld</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
     <repository>
      <id>helloworld-releases</id>
      <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-releases</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>helloworld-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
      <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>



    <!--Additional taken from wallet project pom, because those are somehow not referenced if this settings is refenrenced - some jars - like ws-encryption-sdk-java-1.6.1.jar are not downloadded -->

            <repository>
                    <id>project-1</id>
                    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>


    </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
```

helloworld

When I run `mvn -U install -Denv=live -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, I still see that the lookup for this particular jar is being done only from https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-public/ resulting in a 502 error -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project something: Could not resolve dependencies for project something:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.amazonaws:aws-encryption-sdk-java:jar:1.6.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.amazonaws:aws-encryption-sdk-java:jar:1.6.1: Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-encryption-sdk-java:pom:1.6.1 from/to nexus (https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-public/): Failed to transfer file: https://helloworld.project.com/repository/maven-public/com/amazonaws/aws-encryption-sdk-java/1.6.1/aws-encryption-sdk-java-1.6.1.pom. Return code is: 502, ReasonPhrase: Bad Gateway. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

**Update**

Maven version - 3.3.9.
Java version - 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `mirrorOf` to `*`, you redirect *all* requests to that repository. So all other mirror or repository definitions are not important any more, everything goes to that repository.

If you want to exempt certain repositories from this rule, you need to define a `mirrorOf` definition like `*,!some-repo,!some-other-repo`.